# Populate a Datagrid with a Linq query

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, linq, datagrid

I have the following datagrid in a wpf form:

```
<DataGrid Name="DataGrid" AutoGenerateColumns="False" VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto">
    <DataGrid.Columns>
        <DataGridTextColumn Header="Name" Width="200"></DataGridTextColumn>
        <DataGridTextColumn Header="Text" Width="200"></DataGridTextColumn>
        <DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Edit" Width="50">
            <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <Button>View Details</Button>
                </DataTemplate>
            </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
        </DataGridTemplateColumn>
    </DataGrid.Columns>
</DataGrid>
```

And I'd like to populate it from my code. I use a linq statement to get the values I'd like to put in the datagrid

```
var query =
    (
        from modules ...
        join ...
        join ...
        where ...
        select new { ID = modules.ID, Name = strings.Name, Text = stringTexts.Text }
    );
```

I'd like to populate the columns 'Name' and 'Text' with Name and Text from the query, but I also want there to be a button in each row, and when that button is pressed, I have to know the ID of the row that was pressed, but the ID does not have to show up on the grid.

How do I populate the grid with these values?

Comment: Have you tried it? Simply set `DataGrid.DataSource = query; DataGrid.DataBind();` and see if it works. The button is a second step

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tell columns to bind to a property using

```
<DataGridTextColumn Header="Name" Width="200" Binding="{Binding Name}" />
```

and so on for other columns.

Then in code behind

```
DataGrid.ItemsSource = query;
```

Comment: Alright! But how do I pass ID as well? Do I have to make it a hidden column?

Comment: @ProgrammerAtWorkL: Simple `<DataGridTextColumn Header="Id" Width="200" Binding="{Binding Id}" Visibility="Collapsed" />`

Answer (score 0):

This should work for you:

```
Grid.DataSource = from x in modules
                  select new
                  {
                      x.Name,
                      x.Text
                  };
Grid.DataBind();
```

Best of luck!